# Write a query to retrieve the top 3 products for each year. Use OrderQty of SalesOrderDetail to calculate the total sold quantity

Tags: mysql, adventureworks

The top 3 products have the 3 highest total sold quantities.Also calculate the top 3 products' total sold quantity for the year. Return the data in the following format.
Year Total Sale Top5Products
2005 1598 709, 712, 715
2006 5703 863, 715, 712
2007 9750 712, 870, 711
2008 8028 870, 712, 711

USE "AdventureWorks2008R2" for MySQL

```
USE "AdventureWorks2008R2";

WITH temp as
(
        SELECT YEAR(so.OrderDate) AS Year,so.TotalDue,ProductID,OrderQty,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sod.ProductID ORDER BY OrderQty DESC) AS [Max_Order_Rank]
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
        JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader so ON 
            sod.SalesOrderID = so.SalesOrderID
        GROUP BY YEAR(so.OrderDate),ProductID,TotalDue,OrderQty
)
SELECT * FROM temp
ORDER BY Max_Order_Rank DESC;
```

I'm pretty new to sql and I'm unable to figure out how to how to get the top 3 products from a particular year.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Do you have one?

Comment: 'm pretty new to sql and I'm unable to figure out how to how to get the top 3 products from a particular year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` to get the top 3 products for each year:

```sql
select year, productid, total_sold
from (select year, productid, sum(orderqty) as total_sold,
             row_number() over (partition by year order by sum(orderqty) desc) as seqnum
      from temp
      group by year, productid
     ) yp
where seqnum <= 3;
```